# Javascript - Canvas setTransform on drawImage for perspective

Tags: javascript, canvas, transform, drawimage

I have a script which creates a 3D cube thanks to canvas. The 3D cube is working fine. However, I have some difficulties to apply on it an image with the right transformations in order to keep the perspective.

The 3D cube is built thanks to canvas line from 4 points. I try to apply the transformation to the image thanks to these points.

Here a fiddle example: https://fiddle.jshell.net/d749ndLL/

And here the main code which build the cube and image:

```
canvas.ctx.beginPath();
canvas.ctx.moveTo( this.p0.X, this.p0.Y );
canvas.ctx.lineTo( this.p1.X, this.p1.Y );
canvas.ctx.lineTo( this.p2.X, this.p2.Y );
canvas.ctx.lineTo( this.p3.X, this.p3.Y );
canvas.ctx.closePath();

this.normal.projection();

var r = Math.sqrt( this.normal.z ) * 300,
    g = r,
    b = r;

canvas.ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" +
    Math.round( r ) + "," +
    Math.round( g ) + "," +
    Math.round( b ) + "," + this.cube.alpha + ")";
canvas.ctx.fill();

if (this.top) {

    canvas.ctx.save();
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg';

    canvas.ctx.setTransform(
        (this.p0.X - this.p1.X) / fl,
        (this.p0.Y - this.p1.Y) / fl,
        (this.p2.X - this.p1.X) / fl,
        (this.p2.Y - this.p1.Y) / fl,
        this.p1.X,
        this.p1.Y
    );

    canvas.ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, fl, fl);
    canvas.ctx.restore();

}
```

I'm really close but I stuck on the settransform() calculation for the drawImage(). The perspective is not correct currently: https://fiddle.jshell.net/d749ndLL/

Comment: Unfortunately (or not) the 2D in CanvasRenderingContext2D is not just there to balance the name. The 2D means that there is no hardware support for perspective. Any possible transformation you apply to an image will ALWAYS have the top, bottom and the left and right edge parallel. You can draw the image pixel by pixel but this is javascript and will never compete with low level GPU shaders. What you do is use the API with the 3D implied. WebGL with three.js as an easy entry point for true 3D.